# AbstractController::DoubleRenderError with my respond_to in rspec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I got this Rails3 action:

```
def export
  respond_to do |format|
    format.tdl { render :xml => @template.export_as_tdl and return }
    format.json { render :json => @template.export_as_json }
  end
end
```

and filter before the export:

```
def find_environment
  @environment = KTEnvironment.find(params[:environment_id])
  raise HttpErrors::NotFound, _("Couldn't find environment '#{params[:environment_id]}'") if @environment.nil?
  @environment
end
```

and this rspec:

```
describe "export" do
  it "should call export_as_json" do
    @tpl.should_receive(:export_as_json)

    get :export, :id => TEMPLATE_ID
  end

  it "should call export_as_tdl" do
    @tpl.should_receive(:export_as_tdl)

    get :export, :id => TEMPLATE_ID, :format => 'tdl'
  end
end
```

I also defined the following MIME type:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/tdl-xml", :tdl
```

When I try to run my rspec tests, I am constantly getting:

```
 1) Api::TemplatesController export should call export_as_tdl
 Failure/Error: get :export, :id => TEMPLATE_ID, :format => 'tdl'
 AbstractController::DoubleRenderError:
   Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".
 # ./app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:135:in `render_exception'
 # ./app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:133:in `render_exception'
 # ./app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:22:in `__bind_1314974553_619675'
 # ./spec/controllers/api/templates_controller_spec.rb:178
```

I have no clue what is happening there. This is my exception rendering code:

```
def render_wrapped_exception(status_code, ex)
  logger.error "*** ERROR: #{ex.message} (#{status_code}) ***"
  logger.error "REQUEST URL: #{request.fullpath}"
  logger.error pp_exception(ex.original.nil? ? ex : ex.original)
  orig_message = (ex.original.nil? && '') || ex.original.message
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      render :json => {
        :errors => [ ex.message, orig_message ]
      }, :status => status_code
    end
    format.all do
      render :text => "#{ex.message} (#{orig_message})",
        :status => status_code
    end
  end
end
```

Ah so the render_exception general method in my api_controller is called. It looks like:

```
def render_exception(status_code, exception)
  logger.error pp_exception(exception)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => {:errors => [ exception.message ]}, :status => status_code }
    format.all  { render :text => exception.message, :status => status_code }
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you tell which lines `templates_controller_spec.rb:178` and `api_controller.rb:22` are?

Comment: My wild guess is that your action somehow raises an exception, which messes the whole thing. Could you also post the `render_exception` in your api controller?

Comment: Added. Also there is a filter before the action. Added that one too.

Comment: Aaaah theres render_exception! So something bad happened. Lemme see.

Comment: What happens if you disable the exception code and let them bubble up? You may see the root cause come up on its own.

Comment: I have added render_exception (lines 133 and 135 there). I am logging there, I will see.

Comment: @Benoit - Got it: ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template api/templates/export with {:handlers=>[:rjs, :rhtml, :haml, :rxml, :erb, :builder], :formats=>[:tdl], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "#<RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering::PathSetDelegatorResolver:0xb5a959d8>" please add something I can check you :-)

Comment: but does your exception render code works outside rspec? You may very well have a problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling your error handler, the root cause should come up on its own.